# Confused by Monotone class theorem for functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability

Monotone Class Theorem has two types. One is Monotone class theorem for sets and the other for functions. I have no doubt for sets.

Here is a reference of definition of Monotone Class Theorem for functions from *Probability: Theory and Examples, Durrett Rick, 4.1-edition*.

> Theorem 6.1.3. **Monotone class theorem**. Let $\mathcal {A}$ be a $\pi$-system that contains $\Omega$ and let $\mathcal {H}$ be a collection of real-valued functions that satisfies:
>
> (i) If $A ∈ \mathcal {A}$, then $1_A ∈ \mathcal {H}$.
>
> (ii) If $f, g ∈ \mathcal {H}$, then $f + g$, and $cf ∈ \mathcal {H}$ for any real number $c$.
>
> (iii) If $f_n ∈ \mathcal {H}$ are nonnegative and increase to a bounded function $f$, then $f ∈ \mathcal {H}$.
>
> Then $\mathcal {H}$ contains all bounded functions measurable with respect to $\sigma (\mathcal {A})$.
>
> Proof. The assumption $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$, (ii), and (iii) imply that $\mathcal {G} = \{A : 1_A ∈ \mathcal {H}\}$ is a $\lambda$-system so by (i) and the $\pi − \lambda$ theorem, Theorem 2.1.2, $\mathcal {G} ⊃ \sigma(A)$. (ii) implies $\mathcal{H}$ contains all simple functions, and (iii) implies that $\mathcal{H}$ contains all bounded measurable functions.

I can't understand one sentence from the proof, "(ii) implies $\mathcal{H}$ contains all simple functions". Why?

P.S.

I think "measurable with respect to $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$" means $\sigma(\mathcal {A})$-measurable. I know $\mathcal{F}$-measurable mapping that is suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and $(E, \mathcal{E})$ are two measurable spaces, $f$ is a mapping from $\Omega \to E$. $f$ is a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable mapping if $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$ for $\forall A \in \mathcal{E}$. So $\sigma(\mathcal {A})$-measurable probably means those $f: (\Omega, \sigma (\mathcal{A})) \to ([0, +\infty), \mathcal{B}{[0, +\infty)})$ where $\mathcal{B}{[0, +\infty)}$ denotes Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0, +\infty)$.

Update:

The author didn't make the sentence clear. So I try to make it a little bit more complete. Let $\forall f$ is $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$-measurable. I suppose $g_n =\sum_{k=0}^{n2^n -1} \frac{k}{2^n} I_{\{\frac{k}{2^n} \le f^+ ＜ \frac{k+1}{2^n}\}} + n I_{f^+ \ge n}$ where $f^+ = f ∨ 0$. Then $g_n \in \mathcal{H}$ coz $f$ is $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$-measurable that is $\{x: \frac{k}{2^n} \le f^+ ＜ \frac{k+1}{2^n} \} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and $\{x: f^+ \ge n\} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$. Then $g_n$ increasingly converges to $f^+$ and so does $f^-$. $f = f^+ - f^- \in \mathcal{H}$. Please note that I can only get simple functions defined on $\{x: \frac{k}{2^n} \le f^+ ＜ \frac{k+1}{2^n} \}$ and $\{x: f^+ \ge n\}$ are in $\mathcal{H}$. I can't prove $\mathcal{H}$ will contains all simple functions. Am I right?

Comment: what do you mean by  Let $\forall f$ is $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$-measurable?

Comment: What is the sentence you find the author didn't make clear?

Comment: @ConradoCosta: "(ii) implies $\mathcal{H}$ contains all simple functions" in the proof. I'm not sure how it imply?

Comment: It is written in my answer. Can I clarify any passage?

Comment: @ConradoCosta:  "$\forall f$ is $\sigma (A)$-measurable". Hmmm, I want to show $\mathcal{H}$ contains all $\sigma(A)$-measurable. So suppose $f$ is arbitrary satisfying  $\sigma(A)$-measurable and show it has been contained in $\mathcal{H}$ .

Comment: I see, so you are trying to prove that $f \in \sigma(A) \Rightarrow f \in \mathcal{H}$, you argument is almost correct. I think it can be improved. For instance, I don't understand the phrase : coz $f$ is $\sigma(A)$ measurable **that is** $ \{x: \frac{k}{2^n} \le f^+ \le \frac{k+1}{2^n} \} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

  Why you say that you can't prove that $\mathcal{H}$ contains all simple functions?

Comment: @ConradoCosta: $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$-measurable means the domain measurable space is $(\Omega, \sigma(\mathcal{A}))$. Since $f$ is a real valued function(means the codomain measurable space is $((-\infty,+\infty), \mathcal{B}((-\infty,+\infty)))$, still by definition, $\{x: \frac{k}{2^n} \le f^+ \le \frac{k+1}{2^n} \} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28827/discussion-between-conrado-costa-and-bear-and-bunny).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple function is of the form $$f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^N a_i 1_{A_i}$$ a finite linear combination of functions $1_{A_i}$ for $A_i \in \sigma(A)$.

We would like to prove that those functions are in $\mathcal{H}$.

So we consider $\mathcal{C} = \{B \in \sigma(A)\mid 1_B \in \mathcal{H}\}$

So $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{C}$ by $(i)$.

Since $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$, $\Omega \in \mathcal{C}$

Moreover, if $A \subset B \in \mathcal{C}$ then $ B \setminus A \in \mathcal{C}$ by $(ii)$

Now take $A_1, A_2 , \ldots A_n, \ldots$ an increasing sequence $A_i \subset A_{i+1}$. Then $A = \cup_i A_i$ is in $\mathcal{C}$ by $(iii)$

This proves that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\lambda$-system containing the $\pi$-system $\mathcal{A}$. By Dynkin $\pi-\lambda$ theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) $\mathcal{C} = \sigma(\mathcal{A})$

So now we know that $1_{A_1}, \ldots, 1_{A_N}$ are in $\mathcal{H}$ for any finite choice of $A_i \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$, by $(ii)$ $a_1 1_{A_1} + \ldots + a_N 1_{A_N}$ is in $\mathcal{H}$.

This is the claim of the author.

If you would like to see that any $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$-measurable function is in $\mathcal{H}$  It suffices to consider $f = f^+ - f^-$ and to prove that $f^+,f^-$ are in $\mathcal{H}$.

The argument is essentially the one you presented.

Let $f$ be  $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$-measurable. define $$g_n =\sum_{k=0}^{n2^n -1} \frac{k}{2^n} 1_{\{\frac{k}{2^n} < f^+ \le \frac{k+1}{2^n}\}} + n 1_{f^+ > n}$$ where $f^+ = f \vee 0$. Then $g_n \in \mathcal{H}$ once  $\{x: \frac{k}{2^n} < f^+ \le \frac{k+1}{2^n} \} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$  and $\{x: f^+ > n\} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ (because $f$ is $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$-measurable). Then $g_n$ increasingly converges to $f^+$. Since $f$ is bounded so is $f^+$ and therefore by $(iii)$ $f^+ \in \mathcal{H}$. The argument for $f^{-}$ is analogous.

this concludes the proof.

Comment: I got trapped by myself. All functions satisfying (i), (ii) and (iii) are included in $\mathcal{H}$ or all elements in $\mathcal{H}$ satisfy (i), (ii) and (iii) coz the first one is much bigger I think.

Comment: I think that none of the above is true. For instance $f = 1_A + 1_B \in \mathcal{H}$ and $f$ does not satisfies $(i)$ so neither  "All functions satisfying (i), (ii) and (iii) are included in $\mathcal{H}$ nor all elements in $\mathcal{H}$ satisfy (i), (ii) and (iii). $\mathcal{H}$ has basic functions $(i)$, linear combinations of basic functions $(ii)$ and bounded limits of linear combinations of basic functions $(iii)$.

Comment: I see. But from (i) you just now $\mathcal {H}$ has basic functions. But you can't say it contains all simple functions coz you don't know what kind of domain you needed and some domain may not be included in $\mathcal{A}$. So I try to show those domain I needed, that is $\{x: \frac{k}{2^n} \le f^+ \le \frac{k+1}{2^n} \} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and $\{x: f^+ \ge n\} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$, will be included in $\sigma(A)$.

Comment: Then I can use simple functions defined on those domains I proved. But these domains are just some of simple functions on power set of $\Omega$. Not " contains all simple functions".

Comment: I think there is something wrong with this proof. With my proof, the Monotone Class Theorem for functions still works. It is not a problem of the theorem. Just a problem of one sentence in the proof.

Comment: should modify ${\{\frac{k}{2^n} \le f^+ \le \frac{k+1}{2^n}\}}$ to ${\{\frac{k}{2^n} \le f^+ ＜ \frac{k+1}{2^n}\}}$.

Comment: Instead of ${\{\frac{k}{2^n} \le f^+ \le \frac{k+1}{2^n}\}}$ it should be  ${\{\frac{k}{2^n} < f^+ \le \frac{k+1}{2^n}\}}$

Comment: No, 0 would be removed and $n$ would work for twice.

Comment: We would like $g_n \leq f^+$

Comment: there are same typos in my original post. I've fixed it.

Comment: Yes. $g_n \leq f^+$.

Comment: several ways lead to rome